# Adding fields to a layout in android programmatically horizontally

Tags: android

I have a linear layout set to vertical where when a button is clicked items are added to it but they are all added vertically.

I would like the fields to be added horizontally each row such that on the next click the new fields are added below the current fields,

setting the layout to horizontal achieves this but on the next click the items are stacked onto each other

This is the xml file

```
  <RelativeLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/toplayout">

    <Button                 <!--..onclick of this fields are added below-->
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/add_household"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"

        android:id="@+id/add_households_btn" />

</RelativeLayout>

<LinearLayout   ..fields are added in this layout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_below="@+id/toplayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/household_items_layout"
   android:weightSum="1">


</LinearLayout>
```

Am adding the fields dynamically and this is the code:

```
 public void add_houses(){   //this is called when the button is clicked

    itemslayout.setWeightSum(1);
    //sets widget items
    Button removeitems = new Button(this);
    EditText surname = new EditText(this);
    EditText first_name = new EditText(this);
    EditText middle_name = new EditText(this);
    Spinner gender = new Spinner(this);
    EditText dob = new EditText(this);
    ...other fields here

    //set fields properties
    surname.setBackgroundResource(android.R.drawable.edit_text);
    first_name.setBackgroundResource(android.R.drawable.edit_text);
   

    //set hint for edit texts
    surname.setHint("Surname");
    first_name.setHint("First name");
    ...

    //set layouts params
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams itemsdetails = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 0.3f
    );

    itemslayout.addView(surname, itemsdetails);
    itemslayout.addView(first_name, itemsdetails);
    itemslayout.addView(middle_name, itemsdetails);
    itemslayout.addView(dob, itemsdetails);
    itemslayout.addView(gender, itemsdetails);

}
```

The above generates  this

[image]

How do i stack up the fields horizontally and yet on button click the new fields are set below(vertically)